# <select>'s not updating with Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

We have a popup containing a form with quite a few <select> tags. In some cases a <select> will appear on the page when it loads with no <option> tags inside, and it will be filled in later. Some already have <option>s defined. In every case, <option>s could be added or removed from the <select>s. We are using Semantic UI and defining the <select>s like this:

```
<select id="select1" class="ui dropdown"></select>
```

It is not updating the dropdowns it creates (the "menu") when the underlying <select> changes. Is there something we need to call when <option>s are added or removed?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this:

```
$('#select1').dropdown('refresh')
```

and the semantic UI menu did **not** update.

**UPDATE 2**
In some cases, the <options>s are "added" or "removed" by just changing their display to none instead of actually removing them from the <select>. In other cases they are actually added or removed. Can Semantic UI handle both of these cases?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to move ahead and created a proof-of-concept to see if there was a way to handle this. I created a mutationobserver to look for changes in the attributes of every  in the popup and have the semantic ui "menu" match the display property of the associated . It appears to be working.

```
function create_select_mo()
{
    //create observer
        var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
            //console.log(mutations)

            //get changed element in select
                var target_el = mutations[0].target

            if(!gel(target_el.parentNode))
            {
                return false
            }


            //find the changed <select>
                var sel = target_el.parentNode

            //make sure the parent is a <select>
                if(sel.nodeName != 'SELECT')
                {
                    return false
                }

            //get <select> wrapper created by semantic ui
                var wrapper = sel.parentNode

            //find the associated semantic menu
                var cur_menu = $(wrapper).children('.menu')

            if(gel(cur_menu))
            {

                //get corresponding element to target element in semantic menu
                    var menu_el = $(cur_menu).children('div[data-value=' + target_el.value + ']')[0]

                //change the menu element to match the style of the <select> element
                    if(menu_el)
                    {
                        menu_el.style['display'] = target_el.style['display']
                    }

            }
        })

    //initialize config to look for changes to attributes
        var observer_config = {
            attributes: true,
        }

    //set observer on each <option>
        var target_nodes = gel('my_popup').querySelectorAll('option') //document.body
        for(var x=0;x<target_nodes.length;x++)
        {
            observer.observe(target_nodes[x], observer_config)
        }
}

function gel(el)
{
    if(document.getElementById(el))
    {
        return document.getElementById(el)
    }
    else if($(el).get(0))
    {
        return $(el).get(0)
    }
    else if((typeof el == 'object') && (Object.keys(el).length > 0))
    {
        return el
    }
    else
    {
        //console.log(el + ' not found')
        return false
    }
}
```